# Expressing entropy density in terms of energy density

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

In some manipulations in the free electron theory, one initially has the energy density $u$ of the system as a function of temperature and it's desirable to have the entropy density $s$ (both volumetric densities). The starting point is generally the identity

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_n = T\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_n.$$
I can then use
$$
            \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_n = T\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_n.
$$
Integrating both with respect to $T$ after dividing through by $T$, we find
$$
            \int_0^T dT'\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T'}\right)_n = s(T) - s(0) \stackrel{(1)}{=} s(T) 
$$
$$
            =\int_0^T dT' \frac{1}{T'}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T'}\right)_n =  \frac{u}{T'}\biggr\rvert_0^T + \int_0^T dT' \frac{1}{T'^2}u = \frac{u}{T} - \frac{u_0}{T} + \int_0^T dT'\frac{1}{T'^2}u = ???
$$

where we have used an integration by parts, the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the third law of thermodynamics (in (1)), and where $u_0$ is the energy density in the ground state. But I can't seem to go further. Is there a way to navigate this last integral? My understanding is that I shouldn't need to refer to anything other than more mathematical manipulations, but I'm unable to see how to go further.

Comment: Many integrals are missing their differentials.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I've put those in now. @Themis

Answer (score 0):

Form $u$ to $s$ (assuming constant $n$ and $V$ throughout):
$$
   ds = \frac{du}{T}
   \Rightarrow
   s = \int_0^T\frac{du}{T}
     = \int_0^T\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)\frac{dT}{T}
     = \int_0^T\frac{C_P}{T} dT
$$
so the final result is
$$
      s = \int_0^T\frac{C_P}{T} dT
$$

Comment: Is there no further simplification to be obtained? By another route I can prove that $s = u/T$ (I think) which is why I ask.

Comment: It is not true that $s=u/T$ because $u=TS$ means $du = T dS + sdT$, which is wrong. The correct result is $du = T ds$ (when $n$ and $v$ is constant).

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is there any way to go further and to express $s$ in terms of $u$ somehow?

Comment: This is as close as it gets for the general case. If we are dealing with an ideal gas, we can start with the partition function and obtains $u$ and $s$ in terms of molecular properties and temperature.

Comment: Hmm. I ask because this is essentially Problem 2a in Chapter 2 of Ashcroft and Mermin (a book I'm self-studying right now) and it seems almost certain that this is what the authors had in mind. If you have the book I would very much appreciate any comment, but understand if you can't.